# Find implementation of function pointer

Tags: c++, google-chrome, function-pointers

I am wondering how to locate the implementation of which the function pointer points to:

eg. I am navigating through chrome source code and want to see the definition of SwapBuffers:
`return get_interface<PPB_Graphics3D_1_0>()->SwapBuffers(
      pp_resource(),
      cc.pp_completion_callback());`

clicking into the SwapBuffers symbol lead me to the function pointer declaration:

`int32_t (*SwapBuffers)(PP_Resource context,
                         struct PP_CompletionCallback callback);`

I am stuck here. how to track down the the real implementation of SwapBuffers?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but this is how I did it.

1. Put the function pointer (or `std::function<>` or `folly::Function<>` or what-have you) in the watch window.
2. Drill down in the data until you find something of type pointer-to-function. In my case, I'm looking at member `folly::Function::call_` which has type `void(*)(folly::detail::function::Data&)`
3. Right-click value -> go to disassembly.  In my case it looked like `jmp foo::FunctionTraits<foofoo<<lambda_foofoo> > (07FF604306B20h)`
4. Paste that address into the disassembly window's "Address" field.  Repeat until you're at your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since a function pointer is being used to call the function it is likely that there isn't *the* implementation of `SwapBuffers`. Instead, there could be any number of some. Potentially the source base you are looking at doesn't even include the version being used as it could in principle be dynamically loaded from a plug-in.

I'm aware of two potential approaches to locate function objects used:

1. It may be possible to just locate all functions with the appropriate signature. Especially with function pointers the signatures have to match exactly (which is not the case, e.g., when using `std::function<Signature>` where convertible types may be taken into account).
2. Track down where the used function pointer is coming from. It was clearly set or passed as argument at some point. In your case you'd look at how the object returned from `get_interface<PPB_Graphics3D_1_0>()` is created. Of course, this function may just return an object created elsewhere and since `SwapBuffers` seems to be a public member of this entity it may be necessary to locate all assignments to the corresponding member.

Given that `get_interface()` is actually a template you might need to combine both approaches. For example, I could imagine that `PP_Resource` is actually the template argument `PPB_Graphics3D_1_0`.

In any case, you won't be able to click you way through the code to find the actually used definition.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this has bugged me for months, and I finally figured a hacky way to do it. Using visual studio, run the debugger, you can then do one of two things to find the implantation:

1- Hover over the function pointer call, it will show you the actual function being called in the popup info line.

2- If the first did not work, right click on the function pointer itself - the execution step should be on the function pointer line -, then right click, and pick "Step Into Specific" then "Indirect Call at xxx" and it will take you directly to the function.

Keep in mind that the target function can change depending on the current pointer.